# identifying combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics

A simple identity can be obtained by the following simple reasoning:
$$e^{ix}e^{-ix}=1$$
$$\left(e^{ix}-1+1\right)\left(e^{-ix}-1+1\right)=1$$
$$\left(e^{ix}-1\right)\left(e^{-ix}-1\right)+\left(e^{ix}-1\right)+\left(e^{-ix}-1\right)=0$$
Expanding the exponent, $e^{ix}-1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(ix)^{n}$, leads to:
$$\sum_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!\,k!}(ix)^{n}(-ix)^{k}\,+\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(1+(-1)^{n})(ix)^{n}\,=\,0.$$ which after taking $x=1$ becomes,
$$\sum_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!\,k!}(i)^{n}(-i)^{k}\,+\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(1+(-1)^{n})\,(i)^{n}\,=\,0.$$
Is there any name for this identity?

Comment: No. Why would there be?

Comment: Let me ask it differently, if I present the last identity without the previous details, how would you prove it?

Comment: More or less equivalent to what you did.

Comment: The equation you have is a little messy and not simplified as much as it could be. You could always write the second sum as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^n}{(2n)!}$$ and the first as $$\sum_{n,k=1}^\infty \frac{(i)^{n-k}}{n!k!} = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-4)^{-n}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^2$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi nice simplification. How do you see the show the last line that you wrote? and how do you see that they are equivalent?

Comment: @Yair Factor out $e^{ix/2}e^{-ix/2}$ from the terms in the line before you switch to series.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I now checked the equivalence that you wrote in mathematica and there seems to be a mistake somewhere as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}<0$ while $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-4)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\right)^{2}>0$.

Comment: @Yair that's what we wanted, they sum to zero don't they?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes :), I got it, thank you!